# Display Custom Post Type Fields

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, custom-field, query-posts

I'm making a website and want to display Events. Therefore I made a Custom Post Type called 'event'.

I'm querying events to show them in a page. The Events I made also have some custom fields like : 'Location', 'Day', 'Month', 'Year' and a category.

This is my code now :

```
    <?php
        $args = array(
          'post_type' => 'event', 
        );

        $events = new WP_Query( $args );

        if( $events->have_posts() ) {
          while( $events->have_posts() ) {
            $events->the_post();

            ?>
              <div class='event'>
                  <div class="event-date">

                  </div>
                  <div class="event-content">
                        <div class="event-title"><?php the_title() ?></div>
                        <div class="event-info">
                            <span>Location: </span>
                            <span>Category: </span>
                        </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
            <?php
          }
        } else {
          echo 'No events!';
        }
      ?>
```

Which only gives me the title. How can I display the custom fields and the category ?

I am fairly new to WordPress development, used to programming in .NET.

Thx for any help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Custom fields are saved in the post_meta table. In your query you got the post title and post ID, so now you have to get post meta.

Use:

```
<?php
get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_location', true );
?>
```

same for the rest of your custom fields only '_location' will change according to field you are getting.
Read more about post meta [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/)

Comment: I will try this function. What about using get_post_custom() ?

Comment: you can use this function as well, you have both options

Comment: Thx! This both seems to work but I'm having trouble reading the exact value out of the array.

Comment: I think you have to use get_post_meta() so you can get exact value for  the custom field. this will reduce your work to get value from array when you use get_post_custom().

Comment: Yes, indeed. But this var_dump($day); returns me string(1) "4"  and <?php $day ?> returns nothing. I am missing something here.. Sry I am still a newb.

Comment: try <?php echo $day; ?>, then you got anything?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50522/discussion-between-fmeaddons-and-nanou-ponette).

Comment: This works! Thx